# Derivative with respect to time using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I looking for a way to declare a variable as a function of time, to then perform the time derivative. i.e.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import cos
from sympy import sin

t = sp.symbols('t')
x(t) = sp.symbols('x(t)')
f = cos(x(t))*sin(x(t))
df = sp.diff(f, t)
```

However, this code generates the following error:

```
    x(t) = sp.symbols('x(t)')
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well why not use `Function` like so

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import sin, cos, Function

t = sp.symbols('t')
x = Function('x')
f = cos(x(t))*sin(x(t))
df = sp.diff(f, t)
df
```

[image: derivative]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by using the "Function" function, as follows:

```
t = sp.symbols('t')
x = sp.Function('x')(t)
f = cos(x)*sin(x)
df = sp.diff(f, t)
```

The result yields the following expression:

```
-sin(x(t))**2*Derivative(x(t), t) + cos(x(t))**2*Derivative(x(t), t)
```